# Клик по элементу JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать скрипт, который при открытии страницы нажимает на тизер с рекламой. 
Скелет:

```
<script>
if (location.search=="")
{

}
</script>
```

Регулярное выражение для поиска элементов на cтранице:

```
(?<=href=")http:\/\/do.traffim.com\/.*(?=" class="traffim-descr-link">)
```

как соединить все правильно?

Comment: Неправильные части правильно соединить обычно затруднительно. А если при этом ещё и сам подход неправильный...

Comment: поэтому и прошу помочь и подсказать, в каком направлении мыслить.

Comment: Зачем искать регуляркой (wtf?) элемент и по нему кликать если можно просто перейти по ссылке?

Comment: @yolosora, да куча причин. От обработчиков на ссылке и подсчёта статистики до target blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('a.traffim-descr-link[href^="http://do.traffim.com/"]').click()
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ!

Comment: @Евгения, если проблема решена, стоит принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.